# Call a function (ofstream) C++

Tags: c++, function, call

Hello I have a probleme with my Code.I don't know how to call the function with the ofstream.

```
//Username
Username(ofstream& reg);
//Password
Password(ofstream& reg);
//Email
Email(ofstream& reg);
//Gender
Gender(ofstream& reg);
```

```
Line(22) The Error is: Expected primary-expression before '&' token
Line(24) The Error is: Expected primary-expression before '&' token
Line(26) The Error is: Expected primary-expression before '&' token
Line(28) The Error is: Expected primary-expression before '&' token
```

Comment: Please give a brief detail about the scenario. What you are trying to do and whats your progress so far?

Comment: What's the purpose of these functions? `std::ofstream` is declared in `<fstream>` header, so what's your actual problem?

Comment: I'm trying to write a Register function and write all the input into a file.I included <fstream>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ofstream &`. Function calls don't include types.